# Java bug or windows bug with file creation time

Tags: java, file, file-io, filesystems, nio

When I delete a file and recreate it, the "Creation time: " is always the same as the time when it was first created.

```
Path path = Paths.get(file);
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path , BasicFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("Creation time: " + attr.creationTime())
```

Add full source code:

```
public class FileCreationTimeTest {

    @Test
    public void testFileTimeCreation() throws Exception {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            FileTime fileTime = getFileCreationTime();
            System.out.println(fileTime);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            FileTime fileTime2 = getFileCreationTime();
            System.out.println(fileTime2);
            Assert.assertEquals(fileTime.compareTo(fileTime2), 0);
        }
    }

    private FileTime getFileCreationTime() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path , BasicFileAttributes.class);
        FileTime fileTime = attr.creationTime();
        file.delete();
        return fileTime;
    }
 }
```

Environment: Windows 7, JRE 1.8.0_25

Is this bug?

Comment: what is file system on the disk?

Comment: and provide please full code of file deleting and recreation